# Having some issues using selecting layer by location syntax

Tags: python, arcpy, wing-ide

My instructions:

> Create a Python script that selects parcels from "coa_parcels.shp"
>   that intersect with the shapefile "floodplains.shp" and creates a new
>   shapefile that only contains the selected parcels.
>
> The location of the workspace and the three shapefiles (coa_parcels,
>   floodplains, and the output) should be treated as user-defined inputs
>   using "raw_input" statements.

Below is example pseudocode for the script for this part:

- Begin
- Get user input for the workspace
- Get user input for the input feature class name (e.g. coa_parcels.shp)
- Get user input for the select feature class name (e.g. floodplains.shp)
- Get user input for an output feature class name (e.g. selected_parcels.shp)
- Set the workspace and overwrite output settings
- Create a temporary feature layer
- Select from layer by location based on the select feature class
- Copy the selected features to a new feature class
- Print a message letting the user know that a new feature class was created
- End

My script:

```
import arcpy

workSpace = raw_input("What is the workspace location? ")
inFeature = raw_input("What is the input feature class name? ")
selFeature = raw_input("What is the select feature class name? ")
outFeature = raw_input("What is the output feature class name? ")

arcpy.env.workspace = workSpace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("coa_parcels.shp", "lyr") 
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(coa_parcels.shp,"INTERSECT",floodplains.shp, "NEW_SELECTION")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("lyr", "selected_parcels")
print "A new feature class",outFeature,"has been created!"here
```

My error is this : NameError: name 'coa_parcels' is not defined

Comment: "name 'coa_parcels' is not defined" is self-explanatory. Looking at its other occurrences, it should probably be a string rather than identifier (=you forgot quotes).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look closely at the line which is throwing the error:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(coa_parcels.shp,
```

By not including the layer name in quotes, you're indicating to Python that it should use a variable `coa_parcels` as the parameter input to the select layer by location tool.

---

*Unsolicited, and unrelated to your error, the Make Feature Layer tool doesn't create shapefiles. Nothing prevents you from including `.shp` in a layer name (clearly, since that isn't where your error arises!) but for "best practices" I would recommend naming layers more distinctly so you don't accidentally try to pass a layer to a tool which would only accept a shapefile.*

Comment: Don't post full-fledged answers to typographic-error problems - they don't have any reuse value.